# ORA-01410: invalid ROWID

Tags: oracle, plsql

I get **ORA-01410: Invalid ROWID** error when executing the following piece of code:

```
DECLARE
        CURSOR c1 IS
      SELECT e.empno,
             e.ename,
             e.sal,
             d.dname
      FROM   emp e,
             dept d
      WHERE  e.deptno = d.deptno
             AND e.deptno = 10
      FOR UPDATE OF sal NOWAIT;
    c2 c1%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
    OPEN c1;

    LOOP
        FETCH c1 INTO c2;

        Exit WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;

        IF c2.dname = 'ACCOUNTING' THEN
          UPDATE emp1
          SET    sal = sal + 1000
          WHERE  CURRENT OF c1;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Please suggest a way to overcome it.

Answer (score 2):

In your code, you are locking the following records in the `c1` cursor result set for the column `sal`:

```
     EMPNO ENAME             SAL DNAME
---------- ---------- ---------- --------------
      7782 CLARK            9451 ACCOUNTING
      7839 KING            12001 ACCOUNTING
      7934 MILLER           8301 ACCOUNTING
```

For example, from another session this query

```
SELECT sal FROM emp FOR UPDATE;
```

will block until the next commit or rollback statement will be issued (check out `v$session`).

I guess the problem is that you are updating the `sal` column values of table `emp1` (and not `emp` one), but these records are not locked. You plan on updating `emp1` records that have not been referenced by the previous `SELECT FOR UPDATE` statement, so their ROWIDs become invalids.
From [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/cursors/current_of.php): The `WHERE CURRENT OF` statement allows you to update or delete the record that was last fetched by the cursor.

In fact, if you change the code like this:

```
...
IF c2.dname = 'ACCOUNTING' THEN
    UPDATE emp1
    SET    sal = sal + 1000;
END IF;
...
```

or if you replace `emp1` with `emp`:

```
...
IF c2.dname = 'ACCOUNTING' THEN
    UPDATE emp
    SET    sal = sal + 1000;
    WHERE  CURRENT OF c1;
END IF;
...
```

it would work.